# PHP function updates DB entry with empty fields

Tags: php, mysql, post, get, sql-update

So Im new to php , and im making a blog site as a starter project. The problem is that I have php function to edit data in exsisting post and update it in DB (MySQL), but whenever I try to update edited entry in DB , it saves the entry in DB with empty fields.

When editing a post, the variables used in original post show up in input fields in the form, so thats working, but when I edit input fields etc and post it again , all the variables are empty, so when I check the edited entry in phpMyAdmin all the fiels are empty.

I know its not SQL injection safe, but for the moment main consern is getting the function to work properly!

And when I try to  echo('Virsraksts ir:'.$_POST['virsraksts']); in the edit function the variable actually comes up empty.

Form

```
<?php
include("blogs_funkcijas.php");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>PHP Blogs</title>
        <meta name="author" content="Gvido Pelše" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0" />
         <meta name="description" content="Tēmas par web">
           <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/blogs.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="forma">
                
            <form method="post" action="blog_form.php">

                <label>Virsraksts:</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="virsraksts" required="required"  value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($edit_virsraksts); ?>">
                <br>
                <label>Autors:</label>
                <input type="text" name="autors" id="author" required="required" value="<?php echo $edit_autors; ?>">
                <br>
                <label>Saturs:</labeL>
                <!-- TEXT AREA NAV VALUE VĒRTĪBAS, TAPĒC, LAI PARĀDĪTU TEXT AREA SATURU, KAD LABO IERAKSTU
                JĀLIETO PHP KODS STARP <textarea>PHP KODS TE</textarea> TAGIEM!-->
                <textarea name="saturs" id="content" required="required"><?php echo $edit_saturs; ?></textarea>
                <br>
                <label>Status</label>
                <select name="statuss" required="required" value="<?php echo $edit_statuss; ?>">
                    <option value="">Izvēlies statusu</option>
                    <option value="aktīvs" <?php echo $edit_statuss == 1 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Aktīvs</option>
                    <option value="neaktīvs" <?php echo $edit_statuss == 0 ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>Neaktīvs</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <?php echo $edit_publisks; ?>
                <label for="publisks">Publisks:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="publisks" id="publisks" value="1" <?php echo $edit_publisks == '1' ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Apstirpināt" class="poga" >
                <input type="reset" value="Atcelt" class="poga">
                </form> 
                <?php
               
               labot_blog();
                ?>
                
            <div>
        </div>
         
    </body>
</html>
```

Blog_list

```
<?php
    include('blogs_funkcijas.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Blog list</title>
        <meta name="author" content="Gvido Pelše" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0" />
         <meta name="description" content="Tēmas par web">
           <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/blogs.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>

        </header>
        <div id="container">
        <section>
            <h1>Bloga ieraksti</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Virsraksts</td>
                    <td>Autors</td>
                    <td>Izveidošanas datums</td>
                    <td>Labošanas datums</td>
                    <td>Statuss</td>
                    <td>Publisks</td>
                    <td>Darbība</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                //While cikls, lai izvadītu datus no DB  masīvā 
                $query='SELECT * FROM blogs';
                $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                
                //Datus tālāk pa atticīgajām sekcijām ievada kolonnā, kvadrātiekavās DB lauka nosaukums [] 
                ?>
                <tr>
                    
                    <td><?php echo $row['virsraksts'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['autors'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['izveidots'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['labots'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['aktivs'] ==1 ? "Aktīvs" : "Neaktīvs"; //shorthand IF, ja 1 aktīvs ELSE neaktīvs  ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['publisks'] == 1 ? "Publisks" : "Nav Publisks"; ?></td>
                    <!-- Pievieno php mainīgo id saitei, un atgriež echo $row ar ['id'] tas id kas ir DB -->
                    <td><a href="blog_form.php?edit_id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Rediģēt</a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } //Noslēdz while ciklu! un aiz while noslēdz table, jo ierakstīšana tabulā beidzas!!! ?>
            </table>
        </section>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Function file

```
<?php

$username ="root";
$password = "root";
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "aka";


$con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);



//rakstzīmju kodējums
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf-8");

//Ja Forma nav aizpildīta tad globālojos mainīgajos
//definē tukšu vērtību
if(!isset($_POST)){
    $_POST['virsraksts']='';
    $_POST['autors']='';
    $_POST['saturs']='';
    $_POST['aktivs']='';
    $_POST['publisks']='';
    $virs_raksts='';
    $autors='';
    $saturs='';
    $statuss='';
    $pub='';
    $result='';
}

//JA GET NAV EDIT MAINĪGIE IR TUKŠI
if(!isset($_GET['edit_id'])){
    $edit_virsraksts="";
    $edit_autors="";
    $edit_saturs="";
    $edit_statuss="";
    $edit_publisks="";
}


//JA GET IR TAD MAINĪGIEM PIEŠĶIR VĒRTĪBAS NO DB TABULAS, SĀKUMĀ TOS IEGLABĀ QUERY
//IZMANTOJOT FETCH ARRAY --> ROW MAINĪGĀ[MASĪVS] VĒRTĪBAS, KO PĒCTAM AR FETCH ARRAY IZVELK VĒRTĪBAS NO ROW 
//TOS SAGLABĀ MAINĪGAJOS EDIT_


if(isset($_GET['edit_id'])){
    $id=intval($_GET['edit_id']);
    $query='SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE id='.$id;
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $edit_virsraksts=$row['virsraksts'];
    $edit_autors=$row['autors'];
    $edit_saturs=$row['saturs'];
    $edit_statuss=$row['aktivs'];
    $edit_publisks=$row['publisks'];
   
    echo $id;
}
    




/*function pievienot_blog(){
    //iesauc global $con lai funkcijā varētu piekļūves mainīgajam 
    global $con;
    //tālāk pārbauda vai globālajā $_POST mainīgajā ir kas ierakstīts ar --- if un isset
    //talāk no globālā mainīgā $_POST['html elementa name vērtība'] vērtībās saglabā php $ lokālajos mainīgajos 
    //if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !isset($_GET['edit_id'])) {
        $virs_raksts=$_POST['virsraksts'];
        $autors=$_POST['autors'];
        $saturs=$_POST['saturs'];
        
        //if pārbaude uz <select> vērtībām ja vertības value="aktīvs" tad mainīgajam piešķir 1 else 0 
        if($_POST['aktivs'] == "aktivs"){
            $statuss = 1;
        }else{
            $statuss = 0;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['publisks'])){
            $pub=1;
        }else{
            $pub=0;
        }
        $query="INSERT INTO blogs (virsraksts,autors,saturs,aktivs,publisks) VALUES 
        ('".$virs_raksts."', '".$autors."', '".$saturs."', '".$statuss."', '".$pub."') ";

        $result=mysqli_query($con, $query); 
    //}
    

}
*/

//EDIT FUNCTION

function labot_blog(){
    
    global $con;
    global $id;
   
        if(isset($_GET['edit_id']) && isset($_POST)){
        $edit_virsraksts=$_POST['virsraksts'];
        echo('Virsraksts ir:'.$_POST['virsraksts']);
        $edit_autors=$_POST['autors'];
        $edit_saturs=$_POST['saturs'];
        if($_POST['aktivs']=='aktivs'){
            $edit_statuss=1;
        }else{
            $edit_statuss=0;    
        }
        if(isset($_POST['publisks'])){
            $edit_publisks=1;
        }else{
            $edit_publisks=0;
        }
      
       $query = "UPDATE blogs SET virsraksts = '".$edit_virsraksts."' , autors = '".$edit_autors."', saturs = '".$edit_saturs."',
        aktivs = '".$edit_statuss."', publisks = '".$edit_publisks."' WHERE id=".$id;
       
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        echo $query;
        if ($result) {
            echo 'Labošanas funkcija izsaukta un izpildīta veiksmīgi!';
        } else {
            echo 'Kļūda: ' . mysqli_error($con);
        }
    }
    
}





?>
```

Comment: The logic here is *very* strange and hard to follow.  But when you load the page you run `labot_blog();`, before the user has actually written anything in the form and posted it back to the server.  Why?  That function appears to update a record, but why do that when the page loads?  That function updates the record with values from `$_POST`, which normally wouldn't exist when loading the page with a GET request except that earlier in the script you have a `if(!isset($_POST)){` block which explicitly populates `$_POST` with empty values.  Why?  This all appears to *by design* write empty data.

Comment: Obligatory, please look into prepared statements when interacting with the database.